# Редактор ресурсов android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Где находится редактор ресурсов в студио, не могу найти, слева в сайд баре есть менеджер ресурсов но туда не получается добавить нужный мне файл

Comment: Что за редактор ресурсов? Я просто в Project view создаю через правый клик->new->... или копипастом, перетаскиванием из вне.

Comment: если я правильно понял что вы пытаетесь найти, то в студии нет собственного редактора ресурсов (как например изображения) - нужно использовать внешние. В настройках студии вы можете указать, какой именно внешний редактор использовать для редактирования изображений.